# Route subdomain to AWS api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Hello I´m using Cloudflare to manage my domain DNS and I want to route
test.domain.com to an AWS rest api gateway. is that possible? or I need to fully host the domain in route53?

I tried with

- created lambda function
- created api gateway (with Authorization set to NONE)
- created a certificate for the domain
- created the custom domain in api gateway

now when I go to test.domain.com I see

```
{
    message: "Forbidden"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course you can do this, if you setup a custom hostname in API Gateway with the domain name as your subdomain you will be given a DNS name. When you configure this you will add a path binding to a stage in API Gateway which will then route traffic to your deployment.

You would then assign this as the value to your DNS CNAME record for your subdomain.

More information about setting up a custom domain name is available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html).

Comment: I created test.domain.com on route53 and it gave me NS and SOA. but how to actually connect it from cloudflare? should I CNAME test.domain.com to route 53? that´s the part that is confusing to me. (www.domain.com is still routing to a different cloud provided that´s why I can´t fully host the domain in route53)

Comment: This does not need to be in Route 53 to work, if you're using CloudFlare you simply add a CNAME record like normal and enter the value from he custom domain in API Gateway

Comment: ok I just CNAME´d test.domain.com to the api gateway endpoint (I had to remove /myFunction) but I´m getting message: Forbidden. thanks for your help man!

Comment: Is this going to your custom domain value in API Gateway? :) It will either be a CloudFront domain or a domain in the execute-api domain space

Comment: I created a lambda function, an API Gteway and I wanted to CNAME to the api gateway endpoint. no cloudfront

Comment: Ok, create the custom domain name as a regional domain using these instructions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html. This will give a url containing execute-api in domain name. Set this as the value of the CNAME. :)

Comment: hey there. I updated the description with things I´ve tried. still no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218626/discussion-between-chris-williams-and-handsome).

Comment: The message you're seeing indicates it is going to API Gateway, does the route you're trying to use exist? If you're accessing the base of your domain (`/`) there must be a method for GET on (`/`)

Comment: we resolved this on the chat. thanks so much Chris!